# How to fix missing classes error in android studio after introducing Androidx in my project?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, gradle

I had a project which was working perfectly fine until I started to migrate androidx in my project. I have very little knowledge of androidx ,therefore, I believe I have messed up somewhere in the build.gradle file with the dependencies. Please help me in this issue. 
I tried migrating to androidx from the refactor menu but the error remains as it is. Then I tried reverting back to android rather than being on androidx only.

MainDrawer Activity XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main4"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main4_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Appbar XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main4Activity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main4" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

MainContent XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main4Activity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main4">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flMain"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout>
```

My Gradle file:

```xml
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.sarthaksharma.contactcard"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: What it the error?

Comment: as your xml sir after migrating to androidx your xml widgets still shows of the simple android. you just need to add theses widgets intoandroidx. e.g  <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/white_color">

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

Comment: Your layout views are not migrated to AndroidX.
Try to use Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX... and Android Studio will do everything for you

Comment: @DmytroBatyuk I tried migrating to AndroidX as I mentioned earlier but the result is the same. Even I tried Invalidate cache / restart.